# how to use cronjob in Octobercms?

Tags: cron, octobercms

Lets suppose i want to delete record with id= 50 from my database with the help of cronjob in octobercms what are steps to do this

i did following things to achieve this 
*1)- In my plugin i put the following code*

```
   public function registerSchedule($schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function() {
         DB::table('fsz_posting_tblposting')->where('id', '==', 50)->delete();
    }); // Defaults to every minute (every execution)
}
```

*2)- In my cronjob area of the server i put the following cronjob command*

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home3/user/public_html/artisan scheduled:run
```

After doing these two steps my record is not deleted and i got the following email in my inbox

**There are no commands defined in the "scheduled" namespace. 
  Did you mean this?

      schedule**
what should i do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Seems some typo in your crontab entry**

> its **schedule:run** not **scheduled:run** `[schedule]`

Corrected entry :

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home3/user/public_html/artisan schedule:run
```

for more information you can referhere:

**Setup :**https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation#crontab-setup

**How to add task :** https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/scheduling

if any doubts please comment.